# Favourite icon conflict with Iframe- What's going on?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, browser

Below is the code from my page which is not working, I mean the fav icon is not showing up.

```
<iframe id="__printingFrame" style="display:none;"></iframe>
<link  rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" />
```

To my surprise, when I change the order

```
<link  rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" />
<iframe id="__printingFrame" style="display:none;"></iframe>
```

Worked like a charm.

Any clue, what's going on here and what I am missing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure why you used both the `<link />` tag and `<iframe />` tag inside `<body>` tag (I assume). The `<link />` tag is supposed to be present in `<head>` tag and the `<iframe />` being a content type tag, should be present in the `<body>`. In the above arrangement itself, `<link />` tag obviously comes first and then comes `<iframe />` tag.

Tags like `<link />`, `<base />` are meta-tags and they should come before any content tags to work.

Comment: They both are in `head` tag. And I am using that iframe which is used by `GWT` and should present in head.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ You cannot have `<iframe />` in a `<head>` tag! `:O`

Comment: But when I change order (in head tag itself), it's working fine.

Comment: From the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe): *However, an `<iframe>` can be used within a normal document body.*

Comment: The ordering reason is that. Meta tags should come before the content tag. `<link />` is a meta tag. `<iframe />` is a content tag.